# Cognito - How to handle multiple simultaneous signins from the same account

Tags: reactjs, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

We have a web app developed with react and we are using aws-amplify to utilize Cognito to handle our user's sessions in.

Right now, our app allows multiple simultaneous signins from the same user in different devices, but this is something we want to avoid.
We want to use Cognito to either:

- Logout open sessions in other devices whenever the user logs in.
- Notify the user who's loging in on a new device that they already have an open session in other devices and ask them if they want to continue with the login process or if they want to continue with their open session in another device.

I saw this thread in the aws-amplify (flutter) package, but since our app is a web app I'm not sure the same process applies to us:
aws-amplify/amplify-flutter#1206

Any feedback you can provide on this will be very helpful.
Thank you in advance for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of Cognito Triggers? You can execute code when certain events happen. For example you can run some code just before a user authenticates:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-authentication.html

In short, write a lambda that logs the user out of every device whenever they authenticate, and assign that Lambda to the Cognito Pre-Auth trigger.

Comment: Hello! First of all, thank you for your answer. I am very new to AWS Cognito, I've recently started exploring it since it is the service the company I work for uses to manage the user's authentication process.

I've read a few things about lambda functions in Cognito but haven't used them yet. I will look into it to solve the situation at hand.